# how to send password from back end (spring boot) to angular and how to decrypt it in angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i want to generate the password of the users in the back end ,but i dont know how to send it with spring boot and  decrypt it in angular (i m using bcryptpasswordencoder)

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
  public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Validated @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
    System.out.println(signUpRequest.getCin());
    if (candidatRepository.existsByCin(signUpRequest.getCin())) {
      return ResponseEntity
          .badRequest()
          .body(new MessageResponse("Error: CIN is already in use!"));
    }
    String x= Generator.generateRandomPassword(6);
    // Create new user's account
    Candidat user = new Candidat(signUpRequest.getCin(), 
               signUpRequest.getDelegation(),encoder.encode(x));
    candidatRepository.save(user);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
  }
```

---

### Ag Service

```
register(user:AuthSignUp): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signup', {
  cin: user.cin,
  delegation: user.delegation,
}, httpOptions);
}
```

---

### Login Component

```
this.authService.register
      (new AuthSignUp(this.cin,this.delegation)).subscribe(
        response  => {
          console.log(response )
          this.password=response ;
          this.signUpSuccessful = true;
          this.isSignUpFailed = false;
        },
        err => {
          this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
          this.isSignUpFailed = true;
        }
      );
```

Comment: Bcrypt is not an encryption, it is a hash. It is on purpose very difficult to get back the cleartext.

Answer (score 1):

In MessageResponse class you can add a new property named data

```
@Getter
@Setter
class MessageResponse<T> implements Serializable{
   private String message;
   private T data;

   public MessageResponse(String message,T data){
      this.data=data;
      this.message=message;
   }

   public MessageResponse(String message){
      this.message=message;
   }

}
```

Now, you can pass data as any type of object since MessageResponse is a generic class . In this case this data will be String

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse<String>("User registered successfully!",PASSWORD WILL BE HERE));
```

In ui part, you can read it from property

```
this.password=response.data
```

Comment: the password is encrypted ! how to decrypt it in angular (im using bcryptpasswordencoder is spring boot)

Comment: What is the purpose of sending password to UI? It is not secure operation...